# Translate formula DELTA = B^2 - 4AC to an assembly language program

Tags: winapi, assembly, x86

I'm totally a beginner in the assembly language. I'm trying to translate `b^2-4ac` in assembly code for simple calculation. This is my code and I can't figure out how I can display the output of this program.
Note: When I run this code in Visual Studio 2019, this executes without any error but doesn't show any output.

This is my code:

```
.386
.model flat,stdcall
.stack 4096
ExitProcess proto,dwExitCode:dword

.data

delta   SDWORD ?
a   SDWORD 6
b   SDWORD 3
cc   SDWORD 4

.code
main proc

    ; b^2-4ac
    mov eax,a 
    mov ebx,b
    mov ecx,cc

    imul ebx,b ; b^2
    imul eax,4 ; 4a
    imul eax,cc ; 4a*c
    sub ebx,eax ; b^2-4ac

    mov delta,ebx ; delta = b^2-4ac

    invoke ExitProcess,0
main endp
end main
```

Answer (score 2):

There are multiple ways that you could do that. The easiest would be to leverage one of the suitable Windows API functions. For example:

```
include \masm32\include\msvcrt.inc
includelib \masm32\lib\msvcrt.lib

.data
fmtString       db "delta =  %d",13,10,0

.code

; ..other stuff..

invoke crt_printf,ADDR fmtString,ebx
```

Comment: I'm getting an error, It say's

```Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State
Error A2006 undefined symbol : crt_printf Project ```

Comment: Works for me. I'm assuming that you have MASM32 installed in C:\masm32. If you don't, you're going to have to find the necessary .inc and .lib file elsewhere.